# Live server vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, порт

Всем привет. Есть некая сеть к которой подключены несколько пк.
На этих пк открыли проекты(сайты) через live server vscode, будет ли у каждого проекта свой уникальный порт? Например у первого пк будет localhost:3000 у второго пк localhost:3492 и т.д или у этих пк может быть одинаковый порт?

Хочу потом просмотреть все активные порты и в дальнейшем перемещаться по сайтам с разными портами

Comment: Вот представьте себе миллионы программистов, которые на "пк открыли проекты(сайты) через live server vscode"  и созваниваются, договариваясь об уникальных портах.

Comment: Live server выбирает сам свободный порт) Понял, ответ нет)